# ember: use fixture adapter and websocket

Tags: ember.js, websocket, fixture

My interface is a curve that changes everytime the server sends to ember a new value of the curve's parameter, and that's happen every second probably.it's very dynamic
So i'm trying to receive the data using a websocket from my golang server.
to load the data in the store , i'm asked to use the fixture adapter.
I opened the socket using:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
activate: function() {
    var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var self = this;

 }
```

});

but i'm asking for the next steps, how to receive the data and load it in the store ?

Thank you!

Comment: this is my model, my store!                                                       
//Post Model
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
     name: DS.attr('string'),
     number: DS.attr('string')
});


App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12, //API revision number
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter({
   })
});


App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("post");
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

You can just push new objects to the store. Take a look at this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dariy/2/edit

In this example the setInterval() method is used, you can easily change this to something like

```
...
var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
var self = this;
socket.on('test', function (data) {            
    self.store.push('post',   {
        name:  data.name,
        number: data.nr
    });
}); 
...
```

However, I don't think the fixture adapter is really designed to use in production environments, but if it meets your requirements, why not.